# ionCube installation :: missing zend_extension CentOs

Tags: php, ioncube

I am in middle of ionCube installation but php configuration is missing zend_extension for ionCube but not specify what is exactly

I am working on CentOs

All well Thanks:)

Comment: You should add it in your `php.ini`.

Comment: @jok : yes so what is it and how there's no hint I could go through the response is : _Please note that the following problem currently exists with the ionCube Loader installation:The necessary zend_extension line could not be found in the configuration._

Answer (score 10):

There were few things I have missed

```
Select the correct bit release

Match the Loader with your PHP version, e.g. for PHP 5.3, ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so (extensions are inside the folder)

Add 'zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so' to php.ini

Restart the server
```

Comment: can you guide where to putt these line?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 parts to the solution that worked for me:

1. symlink the 00-ioncube.ini file into the `conf.d` directory from the `mods-available` directory. Do not simply copy the file into the conf.d as the loader-wizard suggests.
2. Restart the fastcgi daemon off and on as well as the apache daemon

See [my blog post](http://metaperl.org/uncategorized/the-necessary-zend_extension-line-could-not-be-found-in-the-configuration) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with installing on Ubuntu. Ubuntu wants a soft link from /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-ioncube.ini to /etc/php5/mods-available/20-ioncube.ini. I tried THAT after following the directions given and apache restart failed with this error: "PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0" in the error log /var/log/apache2/error.log

The solution that worked for me was to delete the soft link and to add the line from /etc/php5/mods-available/20-ioncube.ini ("zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so") to /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Possibly of note, I removed spaces on either side of the equals sign.

Apache restarted successfully and clicking the test link in the loader script page resulted in a success message as did subsequent script execution in my development environment dependent upon ioncube.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ioncube needs its own ini files in php.d directory. Ioncube read its own file with the name of 20-ioncube.ini file.

So to do this we need to create vi /etc/php.d/20-ioncube.ini and add text: "zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so" in it. Now reload php-fpm and browser. Ioncube will find zend framework now.

Comment: Incorrect. PHP reads the .ini fies, not the ionCube Loader, which only runs as a *result* of PHP reading a php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute my install ioncube script in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/rangerz/271504c282ea254779ddb730605fd662), install_ioncube.sh

Or manual install follow the official wizard in other script

```
# run-loader-wizard.sh

curl -O https://www.ioncube.com/loader-wizard/loader-wizard.tgz
tar zxvf loader-wizard.tgz

cd ./ioncube
php -S localhost:8000

# open http://localhost:8000/loader-wizard.php
```